# Read first character on each line in a file

Tags: java, file

I have a file in this format:

```
0 2 4
3 2 4
3 5 2
1 8 2
```

My aim is to read the first line on each file and store it in a array. So at the end I should have `0,3,3,1`

I thought one approach would be, read the line **until** we encounter a space and save that in a array...but it would keep on reading 2 and 4 after

Is there a efficient way of doing this, my cod is shown below:

```
openandprint()
{
int i = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("final.txt"))) 
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int change2Int=Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
        figures [i] = change2Int;
        i++;
        }
    }
catch (Exception expe)
    {
    expe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: what about reading the whole line and getting the first char into an array?

Comment: Is that efficent though?

Comment: You're already reading the whole line into memory anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) would make the code considerably cleaner:

```
private static openandprint() throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner("final.txt")))  {
        String line;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            int change2Int = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine(); // ignore the rest of the line
            figures [i] = change2Int;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes the most sense. No need to load an entire line when you only care for the first integer.

Comment: @Rubixus What do you `s.nextLine();` does then? It doesn't magically ignore lines. It still reads it, just that ignores in the code.

Comment: @Mureinik If one wanted to lets say read the second number only? Is that possible

Comment: @lecardo Add a `s.nextInt()` just after `while` statement, to skip the first number. That's the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int change2Int=Integer.parseInt((line.trim()).charAt(0)-'0');
```

or

```
int change2Int=Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(0));
```

with your approch you are reading the whole line and parsing it to int which will give you `NumberFormatException` because of the space between the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = ...;
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] parts = line.split(" ");
  int next = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
  System.out.println("next: " + next);
}
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?